# Batch script unable to make a closing bracket ) when writing to a vbs

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I am trying to create a vbs through a batch file. But there is a line where I include an object. Batch file is unable to write closed bracket ) into the vbs which is causing an error while running the vbs.

The batch file code is:

```
echo Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> zipIt.vbs
```

output:

```
 echo Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"
) 1>>zipIt.vbs
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

vbs zipIt.vbs

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"
```

vbs output:
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\arvind\Desktop\zip\zipIt.vbs(1, 42) Microsoft VBScript compilation er
ror: Expected ')'

Comment: What OS (xp, win7, win server 2003 etc)? This works fine for me in Win7 & WinServer 2003.

Comment: are you sure that you have posted **exactly** the same contents? it works in my win7 and winXP

Comment: I tried it on win 7 machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^) >> zipIt.vbs
```

Comment: After some review I "undelete" my posting `:>)`

Comment: Yes, you are right :). Outside a code block is escaping not necessary. But inside a code block the interpreter searches for the next matching parenthesis and stops at the **match** here. Escaped closing parentheses are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Like Endoro said:

Try this:

```
echo Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^) >> zipIt.vbs
```

Your error message suggest, that your line is part of lines which resides in a parenthesis block.
Therefore you got problems with closing brackets (also inside echo statements).
You can avoid this problem with escaping the closing brackets.

Form your comment I would suggest to try something like this.
It uses only one redirect for the complete block, it's faster and more reliable.

```
(
  for %%a in (dummy) DO (
    echo Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo oShell.someMethod
  )
) > zipIt.vbs
```

Comment: yes jeb this codes are inside a for block and also I get an error saying: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

When you echo any code, you should always help the batch interpreter with what is text and what is batch code. So always escape brackets, less and greater signs and similar possibly batch code parts with a caret "^". Thus they are interpreted as normal text.